# Magento 2, how to do getViewFileUrl in html file

Tags: magento2, email-templates, transactional-mail

In `phtml` file I use

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/logo.png'); ?>'
```

How to do same in `html` file ?

Answer (score 0):

you might have got your answer as it is an old post but I came across this today. **PHP may not directly be written in `.html` files**. If you want to then you might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312349/7544279) discussion.

Magento does not consider it good practice at first. So, **only way** I can think of using that particular function for your html template is through the **use of Javascript**.

You can extend magento's core **requireJS** modules that defines this function then **change any attribute of your DOM through JS**.

Comment: But thanks, may come handy to someone else